# How do I correctly wait some time between two calls of the same function?

Tags: java, android, wait

So I've been trying to make a small pause of two seconds between every time I want to write a new message using "setText".

```
public void startNewGame() throws InterruptedException {

            welcomeMessage("Welcome.");

            if (!seenTutorial) {
                seenTutorial = true;
                welcomeMessage("This is the first message.");
                welcomeMessage("This is the second message.");
                welcomeMessage("This is the third message.");
            }
        }


      public void welcomeMessage(String message) throws InterruptedException {

            welcomeText.setAlpha(0f);
            welcomeText.setText(message);
            welcomeText.animate().setDuration(2000).alpha(1.0f);
        }
```

I've tried wait(2000), but the program crashes.

Also tried to surround the content of welcomeMessage method with:

```
    public void welcomeMessage(String message) throws InterruptedException {
     Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                         welcomeText.setAlpha(0f);
                         welcomeText.setText(message);
                         welcomeText.animate().setDuration(2000).alpha(1.0f);
                    }
                }, 2000);   //2 seconds
}
```

this way, only the last message "This is the third message." would appear.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Welcome.
"2 seconds pause"
This is the first message.
"2 seconds pause"
.

Comment: Make sure you're running the code that changes the UI on the *UI thread*: https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui#java

Answer (score 0):

What appears to be happening is that your `Handler` is being triggered two seconds after it is created, not two seconds after the previous handler had done its thing.

You will likely want to set separate delays on each of your welcome messages.  This would mean 2 seconds for the first message, 4 seconds for the second, and 6 for the third.

Comment: Excellent news! Don't forget to upvote and accept (tick) this answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the `welcomeMessage`method you are creating new `Handler` each time that posts a `r
Runnable` that is scheduled to run delayed on the same thread that the `Handler` was created on.

So what happens is these 3 runnables will all run after your 2000 millis, so thats why you see only the efect of that third runnable. So yeah, you can schedule them with different delay (so there is a time gap between them), ie 2000, 4000, 6000.

```
 public void welcomeMessage(String message, int delay) throws InterruptedException {
     Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                         welcomeText.setAlpha(0f);
                         welcomeText.setText(message);
                         welcomeText.animate().setDuration(2000).alpha(1.0f);
                    }
                }, delay);   
}

showMessage("hello", 2000);
showMessage("lets play the game", 4000);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, and for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

instead of call a method three times and putting it in handler try this

store the messages in a string array

```
    String[] messages = {"This is the first message","This is the second 
                           message","This is the third message"}

    public void welcomeMessage() throws InterruptedException {
         int i=0;
while(i<messages.size()){
         Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                             welcomeText.setAlpha(0f);
                             welcomeText.setText(message[i]);
                             welcomeText.animate().setDuration(2000).alpha(1.0f);
                        }
                    }, 2000);   //2 seconds
                  i=i+1;
    }
```

}